# How to Connect to localhost with SSH(PuTTy)

Tags: putty

I just figured how to connect to my webhost with PuTTy .

But how to I connect to my localhost? I put

Servername: localhost
port: 22 (I've tried 80 too)

And it gives me an error "failed to connect"

How do I connect?

Comment: Make sure you have a SSH server started on your `localhost` first.

Comment: Are you trying ssh or telnet?   You have to have processes running locally to service requests - like maybe telnetd or sshd

Answer (score 7):

If you are using Cygwin on your local host, you can connect to Cygwin's `sshd` (SSH Daemon).

3 easy commands to install the sshd as a service: (always there when you startup the machine)

```
$ ssh-host-config -y # enable sshd. "-y" answers yes to all queries.
$ cygrunsrv --start sshd # start it as an autostart Windows service
$ ssh localhost # try to recursively log in via ssh
```

Taken from: http://nfnaaron.posterous.com/tag/puttycyg#Section2
     (The second approach)

=> You get the entire ssh infrastructure: public key authentication, ssh-agent, etc...

Comment: Just adding. You can use super putty to manage your putty connections and you can connect to cygwin on localhost. I am using it to start my localhost ssh connection.

Answer (score 3):

Ensure that you have running a SSH server (such as openssh-server) running on localhost and not just a web server (such as apache). Also ensure, that localhost is really mapping to 127.0.0.0/8

Answer (score 3):

The solution in the answer above won't work unless you have installed Cygwin with the OpenSSH package selected - you have to do this manually during the installation process (see option a below).

Depending on the intended purpose of your connection you can try one of the options below, option (b) being much easier to install but lacking the *nix shell capabilities.

**a**. You can install a Cygwin shell with ssh server, this site (http://ist.uwaterloo.ca/~kscully/CygwinSSHD_W2K3.html) has instructions for Windows Server but they work for other Windows too with may be some of the questions shown in the output on the page not appearing on non-server version of Windows. Also, where it says in the instructions to issue the command:

> mount -s --change-cygdrive-prefix /

delete the -s option so that the command is

> mount --change-cygdrive-prefix /

(at least this was the case for me on Windows 7).

**b**. PuTTy site suggests WinSSHD (http://www.bitvise.com/winsshd-download). It's an easy self-installer. Once it's up you have to click onthe StartSSHD link about 1/3rd of the screen down on the first page of the config window. Then you can connect your PuTTy to localhost. However, in my experience, it didn't provide any *nix command support, only the native Windows ones and I couldn't find anything in their user guide on this.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Complete Solution:

1. Install the OpenSSH-Server module.
2. Run Windows PowerShell as an Administrator to enable the "sshd" service and to set it to start automatically on startup in the future. We also need to configure a few firewall rules.

The above tasks can be performed by following the instructions given on: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse?tabs=powershell

3. Open PuTTY

In the Host Name (or IP address) section, enter localhost or 127.0.0.1 [Port-22]

Click on Open

A PuTTY Security Alert opens up to confirm the ssh-server-key-fingerprint, Click on Accept / Connect Once

Now, Enter your system-user-name [>whoami in MS Windows Command Prompt]

Enter the password that you use as your system-user-password.

SSH connection to MS Windows Command Prompt using PuTTY for system-user@localhost / system-user@127.0.0.1 is successful.

Answer (score 0):

The point of SSH is to let you run commands over the network on a **different** computer. Localhost is the computer you are actively using.

You **can** install a local SSH server (as several other answers to this question suggest) but unless you are explicitly testing something using SSH, there's no need.

You can just open a local terminal and shell instead (be it xterm + bash on Linux, Terminal with zsh on Mac, Powershell on Windows, or something else).

Answer (score -3):

Just adding this answer in case anyone is still looking for a solution.

- In your hostname (or IP address) section, enter `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`
- Leave the port to its default value `22`
- Click on `open`

Now a login shell will popup -

- Log in as your `username`, your `username` is basically what you get when you type `whoami` in your Terminal.
- In the password section, type the password that you use as your **system's password**.

The above steps should connect localhost with ssh(PuTTY)

Comment: I'd love this to work, but I get a "network error: connection refused" when the shell pops up. Am I overlooking something?